# How to find width of inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I couldn't find any other questions asking the same thing, though that may be a problem with my search phrasing.

I'm trying to figure out how to find the largest width of all elements contained inside of a container div with a fixed width. So, in the image below, the black box is the container div with a fixed width. The red box represents the contents of the container div, which are subject to change. I want to find the width of the red box, using only the black box in js.

[image: display of container div and larger div inside]

Here is a jsfiddle with what I've been working on/trying:

http://jsfiddle.net/w87k5/1/

the current jquery functions I've tried, with no success:

```
.width();
.innerWidth();
.outerWidth();
.scrollLeft();
```

Note: I do not know ANYTHING about the contents of this container. They could be any html element or mix of html elements, from divs to imgs to iframes. I could put a "red box" without a fixed width surrounding them. Overflow of the black box will be hidden.

Update: There could be any number of children in the container. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w87k5/3/

Update 2: I'm going to run benchmark speed tests on all of the answers to see which one is the fastest, and select one after that. Thanks for all your input!

Benchmarks: 
I generated 1000 divs with a random width of inbetween 0 and 100, recorded the Date().getTime(), did the test, then recorded time again. Here are the results:

~2418 avg. milliseconds with the for loop for length. I might have messed this one up somehow?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++){
        var q = $("#box :nth-child(" + i + ")").width();
        if(q > box){
            box = q;
        }
    }
```

~34.4 avg. ms for the .each loop.

~22.4 avg. ms for the .map function. (Chosen answer.)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/w87k5/2/

Comment: @JoshC that will only return first child value , any jQuery getter working on collection  only returns the first

Comment: Aw, you got my hopes up (while also making me feel dumb). Charliefl is right I think, that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need all nested elements can search with `*` selector which will return all descendent elements:

```
var widthArray=$('#box *').map(function(){
   return $(this).outerWidth();
}).get();

var maxWIdth= Math.max.apply(Math, widthArray);
```

For just children:

```
var widthArray=$('#box').children().map(function(){....
```

Comment: ooops   typo   was missing capital on `W`...works here http://jsfiddle.net/w87k5/5/

Comment: I benchmarked the answers, this one is definitely the fastest, which is why I chose it. (See Benchmarks above.)

Comment: Cool, I'll try and remember that for nest time!

Answer (score 2):

Get the number of children, and loop through to get the width of each

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
       var count = $("#box").children().length;
       var h = 0;

       for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
           max = $("#box :nth-child(" + i + ")").width();
           var h = Math.max(max, h);
       }
           alert(h);
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JDVN3/1/

*Please not that the index starts from 1 and not 0.*

Check out: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: The first one returns a lengthy error, and the second one only checks the 2nd child. Though I could loop through the children, that isn't ideal.

Comment: $("#parentselector").children().length; get the number of childs and then loop using this variable instead of 2..

Comment: You might want to check that fiddle - it doesn't reflect the coding you're using.

Comment: Changed the link, check out

Comment: `alert` doesn't really resolve issue of finding maximum as per OP request

Comment: Well, once you find width of all elements it should be pretty easy to find the max, anyways have changed the code to reflect it..

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to cycle though each child element.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/w87k5/4/)

```
var widths = [];
$('#box').children().each(function(i){
    widths[i] = $(this).width();
});
alert(Math.max.apply(Math, widths));
```

Which will return the width of the child element with the largest width.