# How to make ancestor height auto change at each level as nested children added/deleted

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

In the current project Im working on I need to be able add multiple levels of sortable nested lists dynamically using jQuery. I have the nested sortable lists working as desired but I'm having issues where the next siblings of the parents visually overlap the descendants of the previous parent siblings as seen at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pkr4Q/14/)

Visually I need each list item to not overlap any of the descendants of its siblings, so my thought was that I need to set the height/margin-bottom  based on the cumulative heights of the descendant elements.

The only attempt I could get to sort-of works is:

```
function resizeHeight(){
    var setToChildrenHeights = function(){
        var height = $(this).height();
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            height += $(this).outerHeight();
        });
        $(this).css('margin-bottom',height);
    }
    $("li").each(setToChildrenHeights);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work when I have 3 levels of nested lists (i.e. the parent is pushed out of the way of the direct children but not out of the way of the children's children.

For reference a sub-set of the google searches I used were:

- "jquery how to make ancestor height auto change at each level as nested children added/deleted"
- "jquery parent height change as nested children added/deleted"
- "jquery list container height to increase as items added"
- "jquery dynamically change height of div when child added"
- "jquery cascading resize when child dynamically added/removed"
- "jquery adjust list element height based on children heights"

As well as searching through the jQuery api documentation, so far I haven't found a solution, I'm hoping another set of eyes will be able to point out my mistake. Any help is appreciated.

update: 
I've had some luck taking a recursive approach with this code ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/riolowry/2UCHX/3/)), but unfortunately it is now setting too much of a margin bottom:

```
function recursiveResize($parentElement){
    var numChild = $parentElement.children().length

    console.log('number of children = '+numChild);
    var parentHeight = $parentElement.height();
    if (numChild<1)
        return parentHeight;
    var height = 0;
    $parentElement.children().each(function(){
        height += recursiveResize($(this));
    });
    return parentHeight + height;    
}

//try2
function newResizeRecursive(){
    var $parentElements = $('li');

    $parentElements.each(function(){
        var height = $(this).height();
        var childrenHeights = recursiveResize($(this));
        var newmargin = childrenHeights - height +3
        console.log('new margin = '+newmargin);
        console.log('before '+$(this).css('margin-bottom'))
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', (newmargin>3 ? newmargin: 3))
        console.log('after '+$(this).css('margin-bottom'))
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have a working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/riolowry/q59qF/14/). @James G.'s suggestion was a good place to start but it turns out that there were 2 issues with re-sizing things:

1. To get the re-size working properly I ended up needing to find all of the leaf nodes and then traverse up the tree, re-sizing each ancestor based on the size of its descendants, like so:

   ```
   function resize(childId){
       //will find all the leafnodes
       var $leafnodes = findLeafNodes();

       //resize all ancestors of each leafnode
       $leafnodes.each(function(){
           resizebyID($(this).attr('id'));
       });
   }

   function resizebyID(childId){
       console.log('resize id='+childId);
       var $child = $('#'+childId);
       var $parent = $child.parent();
       var $grandparent = $parent.parent();

       //traverse each ansestor height in order
       $child.parentsUntil('#builder').each(function(){
           if ($(this).is('form')){}
           else{
               var heightsA = $(this).children().map(function(){
                  return $(this).outerHeight();
               }).get();
               var heightsum =0;
               for(var i=0; i<heightsA.length; i++)
                   heightsum += heightsA[i];

               $(this).css('margin-bottom',heightsum);

               console.log('ancestor:'+ $(this).attr('class')
                           +' height='+heightsum);
           }
       });
   }

   function findLeafNodes(){
       //try this, from #builder find the deepest child nodes 
       //and then resize each up the node from there:
       function innerMost( root ) {
           var $children = $( root ).children();

           while ( true ) {
               //set uniqueIDs so resize can work
               $children.each(function(){
                   $(this).uniqueId();
               })
               var $temp = $children.children();
               if($temp.length > 0) $children = $temp;
               else return $children;
           }
       }

       var $inner = innerMost($('#builder'));
       return $inner;
   }
   ```
2. I needed to re-size not only when elements were added but also when on the sortable events were triggered. So I setup the sortable objects so that resize() was called when the events were triggered:

   ```
   function getSortableContainer(containerClass) {
       var $sortableContainer = $('<ul class="' + containerClass + '"></ul>');
       var sortOptions = {
           placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
           opacity: 0.5,
           connectWith: '.' + containerClass,
           change: function (event, ui) {},
           stop: function (event, ui) {
               console.log("New " + containerClass + " position: " + ui.item.index());
               resize(childID);
           }
       };

       $sortableContainer.sortable(sortOptions);
       $sortableContainer.disableSelection();
       console.log("new " + containerClass + " added");
       return $sortableContainer;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767994/how-to-find-width-of-inner-elements) that I asked, I believe we can rework the code for yours. Unfortunately, your fiddle has only succeeded at confusing me, so I won't be updating it.

Every time you append an element, you should resize the parent and the parent's parent, using `maxHeight` as returned by this function:

```
var heightArray=$('#builder *').map(function(){
   return $(this).outerHeight();
}).get();

var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heightArray);
```

I think you should just need to switch out `#builder` for the parent element's id.

In the future, with JSfiddle, you should avoid including extraneous information and keep the code simple. There ARE reasons that you might want to append the buttons with javascript, however in jsfiddle it would be easier to see if you just used the HTML area.

Comment: OK, so in the case of your code example I would then do something like: `$('#builder').outerHeight(maxHeight);` ? I've been using jQuery for about a week so still getting a feel for these things. Thanks.

Comment: Also thanks for the sugesstion regarding simplifying the fiddle, I'm just not sure how to make a simpler fiddle. I can't use hard-coded html because: 1. my requirements are that absolutely everything in #builder be dynamically generated, 2. each nested list must be sortable with each other list at its own level. I've done my best to simplify the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/riolowry/q59qF/6/), clearly commenting where I need help and where the code for setup starts. I'd welcome pointers on how to make a simpler working example that meets my requirements, thanks.